# How to turn off a higher supply from a lower one?

Tags: power-supply, battery-operated, switching, dual

I have a circuit powered by two 12V batteries in series (total of 24V). When switch A is ON, my circuit powers a regulator that outputs 5V to a board I'm using. I'd like to add a second switch (switch B), that taps onto the 12V of one of the batteries (the lower, so both 24V and 12V supplies would share the same ground).

How can I make a circuit such that when switch A is OFF and switch B is ON, it will drive 12V to my board, and when switch A is ON and switch B is ON or OFF, it will drive 5V to my board?

Note, my board has a regulator that takes up to 16V and regulates internally to 3.3V.

I need the 24V to drive motors, and the 12V circuit to drive lights. When I turn the switch to the 24V circuit (switch A) it powers an ESC (electronic speed controller) that provides 5V to my control board. At times, I would like to turn on just the circuit for the lights (switch B), without turning on the 24V circuit (switch A). But for that to work, I need the 12V circuit to power up the control board if the 24V circuit is off.

Note: my control board (not the ESC) that takes the 5V input has internally a regulator that can take from 3.3V up to 16V and regulates it internally to 3.3V.

So, in essence, what I'm trying to accomplish is that when switch B is ON and switch A is turned on, I'd like to ensure the power to my control board comes from the ESC's 5V. But if the 24V switch isn't on, I'd like the 12V switch to power the control board. Hence why I would need to turn the 12V off from a 5V supply.

Comment: Why are you writing comments on your own post? Put *all* the details in the post. Your question is unclear. Where does the 5 V come in? Tapping off one battery is generally a bad idea because you now have uneven discharge.

Comment: It is also unclear if you want to use actual switches and need to figure out the wiring, of if you need to control the power routing from a lower supplied circuit....

Comment: relays or logic-level n-chan mosfets sound in order...

Comment: Why not use an adjustable regulator and switch it between 5 and 12V?

Answer (score 1):

First create a truth table. With two switches there are four combinations but you have only specified three.

```
A    B    Board
-----------------------
0    0    not specified
0    1    12 V
1    0     5 V
1    1     5 V
```

Then it becomes easy to work out the switch logic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP41aG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Electrical schematic from the switch logic. Note that this implementation cuts feed to the board when both switches are off.*

Regarding tapping off one battery: as I mentioned in the comments, tapping off one battery is generally a bad idea because you now have uneven discharge.

Answer (score 0):

You have two batteries in series.

If you draw current from only one (like the lower 12V one) then it will discharge quicker than the other.

If the current is high enough, then the lower battery will be spent while the upper one still has capacity.

If you recharge them in series, then in order to charge the lower one fully, the upper one will have to overcharge.

There is a risk to reduce the cycle life of the batteries substantially.

It would be simpler to use a switching converter to generate the low voltages from 24V, keeping current draw equal from both batteries.

Comment: The 12V circuit will be used for LED lights, which don't draw much current compared to the 24V circuit, which needs power to run 2 200W electric motors (about 13A at maximum speed).